# How to know if MongoDB query using Mongoose returned a Document

Tags: node.js, if-statement, mongoose, undefined, mongodb-query

Hi I am doing a query to check if I have a user in my database. I am using Mongoose in Node.JS.

This is my query :

```
var user;
users.findOne({'fbUID': '1234'}, setFoundUser)

var setFoundUser = function(err, userFound){

if (err) return handleError(err);
user = userFound

}
```

Well, I am trying to check if the result of the query to see if it returned a document from the Database. This is how I check it:

```
function getUserFound(){
    return user;

}

var user= getUserFound();

if(user !== undefined ){...
   //do something
}
```

but, Even when my query returns a document, in other words, the user exists, it never goes inside the if above. 
      For example, if the user exists the 'user' variable will receive the document returned from the DataBase, but I don't know how to check if it is undefined or not.

if user exists it should goes inside the if, but if it does not exist in the database, what is Mongoose returning? false, null, undefined? nothing?

How can I check that the query does not return any document?

Does someone know?

Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: You are defining `user` twice, I also updated my answer with a little more complete code. Since Node is event driven, it will use the callback to notify the other objects.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. I will try everything here and I will post the result. No, the first user receives the data  from the database, the second user variable is in other file and receives the user returned by the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `user` twice in your code btw.

You don't really need a new function to `getUser();`

I would recommend doing something like this (you may have to `toString()` the hid, but I'm pretty sure you don't:

```
var user;

function getUser(uid, callback) {
    users.findOne({'fbUID': uid}, function(err, userFound){

        if (err) return handleError(err);
        callback(userFound);
    });
}

getUser('1234', function(userAccount) {
    if (!userAccount) {
        //handle stuff
        return;
    }

    user = userAccount;
    // check to make sure the user is returned
    console.log(userAccount);
}
```

Even though the below is recommended for checking for null... you have to make sure the method finishes before checking the variable. In Node.... stuff works a little differently than traditional programming.

For instance:

```
var record1 = dbCall1(); // takes 5 seconds to return a record
var record2 = [0,1,2]; // instant
if (!record1) {
    // this will always be true because this statement gets executed right away (not after the 5 seconds are up)
}
```

Node doesn't wait for the dbCall1() to finish before moving on in the code... That's I used a callback in my example. So, in my example... it knows what to do and how to notify you because it notifies (`callback`) when it's done so that you can continue.

Comment: I am gonna try it. Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: No problem, the whole 'undefined' vs. 'null' thing when you're essentially checking for an empty obj can be a pain.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: Not yet. I got another problem. WHen I finish, I am gonna check this again.

Comment: Updated with a little more thorough answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the check to see if user is found is OUTSIDE of the findOne()'s callback. when you do:

```
if(user !== undefined ){...
   //do something
}
```

findOne() is not completed yet.  Therefore, user is undefined. That's why it never goes inside this if statement.  This if statement should be inside findOne()'s callback (which is setFoundUser() in your case).  Here is the revised code:

```
users.findOne({'fbUID': '1234'}, setFoundUser)

var setFoundUser = function(err, userFound){

  if (err) return handleError(err);
  if (!userFound) {
    // inform caller that no user found
  } else {
    // user found, do something with userFound
    console.log(userFound);  // this should print the user object
  }
```

}

Comment: I do appreciate your answer, but I can get the user from the database because I set it inside the findOne method, and I return it by using another function "getUserFound()" and I can print the user object. But even this, it does not go inside the if. :/ I updated the question.

Comment: The purpose of the callback (setFoundUser() in your case) is to do something with the result, try to assign it to something else or return it will not work.

Comment: well, it will eventually get assigned to user but that's when the query is done.  The check if (user !== undefined) {//do something;} is outside of the callback (setFoundUser()). That check will get executed before setFoundUser() get called.  Therefore, the check user !== undefined or !user will always be true unless it's moved inside the callback (setFoundUser()) as in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am using an async function and nestsjs with mongoose.

```
const sender = this.contactModel.findOne({account:transferDtos.sender});
if(!(await sender)){
   return "invald sender";
}else{
   return sender;
}
```

so without the async, we can do something like this

```
if(!sender){
    return "invalid sender";
 }else{
    return sender;
 }
```